# Show eprint field despite doi using biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex

I would like to show both the doi and the eprint field in the references, however it only shows the doi, even after enabling eprint=true. How can I force biblatex to also show the eprint field under apa style? (I realize that this may not be in line with APA style, but I would like to present readers with both the doi of the article as well as a preprint of it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, eprint=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[symbolpackage=pict2e, symbol=plos]{biblatex-ext-oa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{dolan1,
    author      = {Matthew J. Dolan and Christoph Englert and Michael Spannowsky},
    title       = {Higgs self-coupling measurements at the {LHC}},
    journal     = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
    volume      = {2012},
    number      = {10},
    doi         = {10.1007/jhep10(2012)112},
    date        = {2012},
    eprint      = {1206.5001},
    eprinttype  = {arxiv},
    }
    @article{dolan2,
    author      = {Matthew J. Dolan and Christoph Englert and Michael Spannowsky},
    title       = {Higgs self-coupling measurements at the {LHC}},
    journal     = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
    volume      = {2012},
    number      = {10},
    date        = {2012},
    eprint      = {1206.5001},
    eprinttype  = {arxiv},
    }
    @article{dolan3,
    author      = {Matthew J. Dolan and Christoph Englert and Michael Spannowsky},
    title       = {Higgs self-coupling measurements at the {LHC}},
    journal     = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
    volume      = {2012},
    number      = {10},
    doi         = {10.1007/jhep10(2012)112},
    date        = {2012},   
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    \nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

With apa-6 this still worked:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `eprint` field doesn't seem to be printed at all in the `article` driver. You can patch it in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, eprint=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[symbolpackage=pict2e, symbol=plos]{biblatex-ext-oa}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{dolan1,
  author     = {Matthew J. Dolan and Christoph Englert and Michael Spannowsky},
  title      = {Higgs self-coupling measurements at the {LHC}},
  journal    = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  volume     = {2012},
  number     = {10},
  doi        = {10.1007/jhep10(2012)112},
  date       = {2012},
  eprint     = {1206.5001},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
}
@article{dolan2,
  author     = {Matthew J. Dolan and Christoph Englert and Michael Spannowsky},
  title      = {Higgs self-coupling measurements at the {LHC}},
  journal    = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  volume     = {2012},
  number     = {10},
  date       = {2012},
  eprint     = {1206.5001},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
}
@article{dolan3,
  author     = {Matthew J. Dolan and Christoph Englert and Michael Spannowsky},
  title      = {Higgs self-coupling measurements at the {LHC}},
  journal    = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  volume     = {2012},
  number     = {10},
  doi        = {10.1007/jhep10(2012)112},
  date       = {2012},   
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{doi+url}}
  {\usebibmacro{doi+url}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{eprint}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]